# How to specify directory path in .bat file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a .bat file next to the (Result) folder. 
The folder contains .jpg files with different names. 
I'm trying to write a .bat file so that it renames all these files in this folder. 
It works, but not completely. Here's the problem: 
 **It only works in the directory the files are in. 
 (I need a .bat file and a folder with files next to it. For this to work).**

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "count=1000"
set a="Result\*.jpg"
for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d /tc %a%`) do (ren "%%f" file-!count:~1!.jpg
set /a count+=1
)
pause
```

Comment: Put `"`s around the second `%%f`

Comment: Yes I have placed.
This only solved the first #1 problem.
Remaining #2, #3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the solution..**
You can just go to the folder by writing the path `cd / d Result`

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d Result
set "count=1000"
set a="*.jpg"
for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d /tc %a%`) do (ren "%%f" file-!count:~1!.jpg
set /a count+=1
)
pause
```

**SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion** Expansion of variables through signs (**!**)
**cd / d Result** go to the Result folder
**set "count = 1000"** variable in which I marked the number of zeros *file-001.jpg*
**set a = "*. jpg"** the variable indicates which files we are looking for.

*(`dir /b /o:-d /tc %a%`)*
**dir** - Displays a list of files and subdirectories. Next, we sort.
**/b** - Display only filenames.
**/o:-d** - Sorts the list of displayed files in reverse order (newest to oldest).
**/tc** - Sort by file creation time.
**%a%** - Call the variable.

**usebackq** Sets the ability to use quotes for filenames *Like this>* **"**.
Specifies the execution of a string, enclosed in back quotes, as commands *Like this>* **`**,
and strings in single quotes are like commands in a character string *Like this>* **'**.

**delims = xxx** Specifies a set of delimiters. Overrides the default space-tab delimiter set.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me (my English is weak and poor), I don't understand what it would be:

> *It only works in the directory the files are in.
>
> (I need a .bat file and a folder with files next to it. For this to work).*

- I suppose you want to rename recursively, here's an edit for that.

```bat
@echo off 


set "_cnt=1000" && cd /d "%~dp0Result"

for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('dir /o:-d /tc /b /s *.jpg
')do set /a "_cnt+=1" && cmd /v /c "ren "%%~fI" file-!_cnt:~-3!.jpg"
 
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1 & goto :EOF
```

**1.** Enter the folder where the bat is:

```bat
cd /d "%~dp0Result"
```

**2.** List your files recursively `dir ... /b /s`

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('dir /o:-d /tc /b /s *.jpg
```

**3.** Increment your accountant

```bat
set /a "_cnt+=1"
```

**4.** Rename your file in a loop using your counter

```bat
cmd/v/c "ren "%%~fI" file-!_cnt:~-3!.jpg"
```

**Obs.** If I am distant from what you are looking for, please let me know...

---

- An alternative based on your answer

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_cnt=100" && cd /d "%~dp0"

for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('dir/b/o:-d/tc/b/s "Result\*.jpg"
')do rename "%%~fI" file-!_cnt:~-3!.jpg & set /a "_cnt+=1" 

%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[CMD/Bat Operator /dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8123)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work#:%7E:text=The%20%25%7Edp0%20that%27s%20a,to%20the%20batch%20file%20itself)**

  [√] **[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

  [√] **[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**